# what is "%abc%" and "abc%" and and "%abc" in couchbase(N1QL) filtering?

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

What is the difference between "%abc%", "abc%" and "%abc" in couchbase where the condition column  is

```
where name not like "%abc%"
 or name not like "%abc"
 or  name not like "abc%"
```

Comment: This is often called a "wildcard" and it's used in many SQL dialects, not just Couchbase's N1QL. There's also the '_' (underscore) wildcard for single character matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `%` is on both ends, there can be additional characters (one or several) *before* and *after* the given string, like "iuherviuhabcnjkdrg" or "fabcp"

If `%` is only at the beginning of the search term, the search is for strings that *end* with "abc", like "oiuztrabc" or "4abc". And if `%` is only at the end of the search term, the search is for strings that *start* with "abc"

Actually in your example, the whole logic is turned around by "is not" - so the opposite will apply to the results.

Comment: if I want to filter on a particular string without using % then what condition should I use ex. name is abc

Comment: if you search for an *exact string*, use it *without* the `%`, and if you search for that string possibly as part of a longer string, use `%yourstring%`

Comment: If skip or don't want to apply all 4 conditions in a column if missing then what should I do? because it not allowing missing fields to produce results.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly what you mean with your last comment. If you want to select all instances that *don't* contain "yourstring" at all, just use `WHERE NAME IS NOT '%yourstring%'`

Comment: I mean if the column does not contain any values it should not apply any filters.

Comment: Also u can use WHERE NOT CONTAINS(name,"abc")  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A maybe you can edit your question to say what problem you are trying to solve. Using LIKE may or may not be the solution.

Comment: Actually, an issue in my N1QL query, I have rewritten now working fine. thanks :) @MatthewGroves